# SQL statement not running in php script

Tags: php

The sql runs perfectly in mysql, but when entered in a query in php, it genetrates a HTTP 500, not sure why?

```
$sel_query="SELECT 
    Class_List.Class_List_id,
    Class_List.class_id, 
    count(Class_List.user_id) 
  AS 
    Total,
    User_Accounts_.user_id, 
    User_Accounts_.firstname, 
    User_Accounts_.lastname, 
    User_Accounts_.ALN, 
    User_Accounts_.EAL, 
    count(if(User_Accounts_.Gender="Male",1,NULL)) 'Male', 
    count(if(User_Accounts_.Gender="Female",1,NULL)) 'Female', 
    count(if(User_Accounts_.Gender="ALN",1,NULL)) 'ALN', 
    count(if(User_Accounts_.Gender="EAL",1,NULL)) 'EAL' 
FROM Class_List, User_Accounts_ 
WHERE User_Accounts_.user_id=Class_List.user_id AND Class_List.class_id=1";
```

Comment: "Male" , "Female" , "ALN" , "EAL" ... instead of double quote use single quote

Comment: Hello, I was edit to make your SQL more readable. No syntax change just add new line and indent to be more easy to read.

Comment: Shirshaks comment tells you the solution, however I would advise you to take a look at the error log file and try to understand the error. In this case you open the string with double quotes, and use double quotes in the string. You need to escape the double quotes or use single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Escape quotes.

```php
$sel_query="
SELECT Class_List.Class_List_id,Class_List.class_id, count(Class_List.user_id) AS Total,User_Accounts_.user_id, User_Accounts_.firstname, User_Accounts_.lastname, User_Accounts_.ALN, User_Accounts_.EAL, count(if(User_Accounts_.Gender=\"Male\",1,NULL)) 'Male', count(if(User_Accounts_.Gender=\"Female\",1,NULL)) 'Female', count(if(User_Accounts_.Gender=\"ALN\",1,NULL)) 'ALN', count(if(User_Accounts_.Gender=\"EAL\",1,NULL)) 'EAL' 
FROM Class_List, User_Accounts_ 
WHERE User_Accounts_.user_id=Class_List.user_id AND Class_List.class_id=1
";
```